# Code runs when run through VBA or Step through. Will not run when macro is attached to a button?

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new at all of this.  I have a code that takes information that is in a worksheet and sets it up to print.  The data for this worksheet is copied from a pivot table in a different sheet with excel formulas.  That sheet and its pivot table updates first when a location is selected, then the person can click a button that will adapt this linked worksheet to the information it contains and set it up to print.

```
Sub PrintIfNotEmpty()
    Dim ra As Range, re As Range, i As Long, R As Range
    ShInv.Rows("1:228").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Call Entry_Point
    With ShInv
    Set ra = .Range("A20:A228")
        For Each re In ra
            If IsEmpty(re.Value) Or re.Value = vbNullString Then
            re.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next re
    End With
    With ShInv.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    End With
    ShInv.PrintPreview

    Call Exit_Point 
End Sub
```

This code runs fine if I step through it (F8), it runs fine if I hit play in the VBA coding section.  As soon as I click the button it does NOTHING.  It shows the circle like it's thinking and says it is doing the work, but NOPE.. No changes take place on the impacted worksheet.

I am at a loss regarding what to do next.  Some locations have 228 products, some have 1.  I need the code to adapt the worksheet so it only prints what is necessary for the inventory sheet.

Also, I have an EXCEL listbox for selection on my dashboard (ActiveX controls are blocked for us).  What is the Worksheet activity that selecting an item from the dropdown list would be?  It is not SelectionChange, as that action is not triggering the macro when a different item on the list is selected (ie the listbox changes).  That only triggers action if the listbox is changed, the user tabs away from the listbox and then clicks on the listbox again.  I just want one that happens as soon as the listbox changes without all the extra actions.

Comment: What is `ShInv`? Doesn't appear to be declared here

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the type of file it is saved as.

Try saving it as an "Excel Binary Workbook". Maybe this can help run your worK?

Comment: working in Excel 2016.  That option is not available.